# Construction of differential of a smooth map between diffeological spaces with respect to internal tangent spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, generalized-smooth-spaces, diffeology

According to **page 5** , **definition 3.1** of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5425.pdf, there is a notion of *Internal Tangent Space* of a Diffeological space $X$ at a point $x \in X$.

Basically if $x \in X$, they defined the internal tangent space $T_xX$  as the colimit of the following diagram(**composite of functors**) in **Vect**, the category of finite dimensional vector spaces:

[image]

where

1. $ DS_0$ is the category with objects all open connected neighbourhoods of $0$ in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and morphisms are the smooth maps between them sending $0$ to $0$.
2. $(X,x) \in Diff_*$, the category of pointed diffeological spaces.
3. $ DS_0/(X , x)$ is the category with objects the plots $ P: U \rightarrow X$ such that $ U$ is connected , $ 0 \in U$ and $ P(0)=x$ and morphisms are the commutative triangles

[image]

where $ p, q \in Obj(DS_0/(X , x))$ and $ f$ is a smooth map such that $f(0)=0$.

4. $F$ is the usual forgetful functor.
5. *On Objects:* $\phi(U)= T_0U$, the tangent space of $U$ at $0$ and

   *On Morphisms:*  $ \phi(f)= f_{*}$ where $ f_{*}: T_oU \rightarrow T_0V$ is the differential of the smooth map $ f: U \rightarrow V$ such that $ f(0)=0$.

*Now after defining the Tangent space of $X$ at $x$ it is natural to ask about the differential of a smooth map.*

**So given a smooth map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ between diffeological spaces I want to construct a morphism $f_*: T_xX \rightarrow T_{f(x)}Y$ in $C$.**

Now $f$ induce a functor $\bar{f}: DS_0/(X,x) \rightarrow DS_0/(Y,f(x))$ in a *natural way* that is

*On Objects:* $p:U \rightarrow X \mapsto f \circ p : U \rightarrow Y$

*On Morphisms* $\lambda \mapsto \lambda$

"**Now given such a map $\bar{f}: DS_0/(X,x) \rightarrow DS_0/(Y,f(x))$ I am tying to construct $f_*: T_x X \rightarrow T_{f(x)}Y$ in $C$ in a natural way**."

In **Page 6** of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5425.pdf it is mentioned that given such $\bar{f}$ one can construct a functor $T:Diff_* \rightarrow Vect$ which is a left Kan extension of $\phi: DS_0 \rightarrow Vect$ along the inclusion functor $i:DS_0 \rightarrow Diff_*$.

**But I can't completely understand  how the above paragraph is related to my question of explicitly constructing a morphism $f_{*}: T_xX \rightarrow T_{f(x)}Y $** in $C$.

*So I thought that the construction might be followed from a following category theoretic reason which I stated below:*

Let $I$ , $J$ and $B$ be  small categories. Let $C$ be a cocomplete category. Let us consider the following :

[image]

where $f :I \rightarrow J$ is a functor such that $ \beta  \circ f= \alpha$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ be any functor.

Now let $g \circ \alpha = F$ and $ g \circ \beta = G$. Let $L_F$ and $L_G$ be the **Colimits** of the diagram $F$ and $G$ respectively in the category $C$.

**My question is the following:**

For the given functor  $f:I \rightarrow J$ such that $\beta  \circ f =\alpha$, is there any natural choice of morphism $f_*: L_F \rightarrow L_G$ in $C$ between the colimits?

I cannot see immediately any such choice.

**Note:** *Here in this post I used the same notation for convenience for different objects, but I feel the meanings are evident from the context.*

*Apology in advance if the question is not upto the standard of this forum.*

Comment: I got my answer. Its easily following from the simple observation which I mentioned at the end of the question.(which can be easily proved using the universal property of colimits). I personally feel that this question is not upto the standard of this forum. So if someone also feel the same and suggest me in the comments section that I should delete this question then I am happy to do that.  Sorry for the inconvenience caused.